# docker - can't change files (wso2)

Tags: docker, wso2

i'm using docker 18.04 and running the wso2 iot-server. I want to change the ip-address using this tutorial https://docs.wso2.com/display/IOTS330/Configuring+the+IP+or+Hostname . Im using the attached docker-compose file. I'm creating a container using

```
sudo docker-compose up
```

Then i run

```
sudo -it -u 0 <container-id> bash
```

navigate to the script directory an execute the script.

After this files like conf/carbon.xml where changed and everything looks good. If I restart the container executing

```
docker container restart $(docker ps -a -q)
```

all changes where discarded. But the strange thing is, if i create a new file e. g. in the conf directory this file remains, even after a restart.
Can someone explain this to me?

```
version: '2.3'
services:
  wso2iot-mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.20
    container_name: wso2iot-mysql
    hostname: wso2iot-mysql
    ports:
      - 3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-uroot", "-proot"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 60s
      retries: 5
  wso2iot-broker:
    image: wso2iot-broker:3.3.0
    container_name: wso2iot-broker
    hostname: wso2iot-broker
    ports:
      - "9446:9446"
      - "5675:5675"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "nc", "-z", "localhost", "9446"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 120s
      retries: 5
    depends_on:
      wso2iot-mysql:
        condition: service_healthy
    volumes:
      - ./broker:/home/wso2carbon/volumes/wso2/broker
  wso2iot-analytics:
    image: wso2iot-analytics:3.3.0
    container_name: wso2iot-analytics
    hostname: wso2iot-analytics
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-k", "-f", "https://localhost:9445/carbon/admin/login.jsp"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 120s
      retries: 5
    depends_on:
      wso2iot-mysql:
        condition: service_healthy
    volumes:
      - ./analytics:/home/wso2carbon/volumes/wso2/analytics
    ports:
      - "9445:9445"
  wso2iot-server:
    image: wso2iot-server:3.3.0
    container_name: wso2iot-server
    hostname: wso2iot-server
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-k", "-f", "https://localhost:9443/carbon/admin/login.jsp"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 120s
      retries: 5
    depends_on:
      wso2iot-mysql:
        condition: service_healthy
    volumes:
      - ./iot-server:/home/wso2carbon/volumes
    ports:
      - "443:9443"
    links:
      - wso2iot-mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, until the container is deleted write-able layer should be available. But this is not the expected way of using Docker. In this case, if you need to run the change-ip script I think it would be better to create a new Docker image where change-ip script is executed in the process of Docker image creation.